# dd: failed to open '/dev/mmcblk0p': No such file or directory in Raspberry SD Card backuping

Tags: backup, sd-card

I am trying to backup of my raspberry Zero SD card by [this instruction](http://kamilslab.com/2017/02/15/how-to-backup-the-raspberry-pi-sd-card-using-linux/), i also mention that my raspberry zero have connected to my PC (Linux LDME) by USB OTG port and using Pi Power supply both together and after that the pi don't recognized to my PC, Now i have bought another Pi Zero and the same with previous SD card new Pi Zero also don't detected by my PC USB Ports,SO i checked the old Pi Zero to another PC (Win XP) and don't detected too, SO i guess it must be from the SD card.

I have not another SD card AND need the data of my SD card so i need to backup the SD card to my pc and then foramting it with new raspbian Installing to it.

When i want to backup the SD card by this instruction:

```
df -h
```

I get this:

```
so@notebook:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.5M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda7       197G   16G  172G   9% /
tmpfs           5.9G  154M  5.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       197G   59G  128G  32% /home
tmpfs           1.2G   48K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda5       732G  406G  326G  56% /media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346
so@notebook:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.5M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda7       197G   16G  172G   9% /
tmpfs           5.9G  154M  5.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       197G   59G  128G  32% /home
tmpfs           1.2G   56K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda5       732G  406G  326G  56% /media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346
/dev/mmcblk0p2  3.6G  3.3G  132M  97% /media/so/rootfs
/dev/mmcblk0p1   43M   22M   21M  51% /media/so/boot
```

And with this instruction:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p of=/home/so/Desktop/trash/raspbian/raspbian_backup.img
```

I get this error:

```
dd: failed to open '/dev/mmcblkop*': No such file or directory
```

you can see below:
[image: No such file or directory]

SO is it recommended to use one SD Card backup software?

Answer (score 1):

there is no `mmcblk0p`, it's `mmcblk0` for the drive and `mmcblkp1` (or different number)for the partition(s)

Answer (score -1):

1. Each time the command failed it's because you mistyped what's written.
2. Don't use `dd` to copy the card while the associated filesystems are mounted (in use). Unmount them first

   ```
   umount /media/so/rootfs
   umount /media/so/boot
   ```
3. That `dd` command is awfully inefficient. Use this instead.

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M of=/home/so/Desktop/trash/raspbian/raspbian_backup.img
   ```

   But do you *really* want to put your file into a `trash` directory?

Comment: No its temporary. thanks for  your answer.

Comment: your answer is some partly uncorrected so it must changed to `It should be mmcblk0 (whole device), mmcblk0p1 (partition 1), mmcblk0p2 (partition 2`

Comment: @SoheilPaper I'm sorry but I don't understand you. If you're referring to my step 3, then all I did was to copy the device name from your question. Usually I'd expect `/dev/mmcblk0` but you'd used `/dev/mmcblk0p` so I used that here, too. I can update my answer if yours was a typo.

Comment: now  `mmcblk0p1` is correct, it seems the you edited your answer , now it is correct.